# UILabel with -[sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode] is cutting off words

Tags: iphone, uikit

`UILabel` inside of a `UITableViewCell`.  On cell tap, height expands and a second `UILabel` appears with various amounts of data.

The problem is, if the line wraps, `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` does not return the proper height and cuts off the bottom line.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    labelExpanded = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
    labelExpanded.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11];
    labelExpanded.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    labelExpanded.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    labelExpanded.numberOfLines = 0;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:labelExpanded];

    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(300, 20000);
    CGSize size = [expandedDetails sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    [labelExpanded setText:expandedDetails];
    [labelExpanded setFrame:CGRectMake(16, 30, 248, size.height)];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(// Row is Expanded)
    {
        CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(300, 20000);
        CGSize size = [sameTextAsLabel sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

        // I found +8 to height added nice padding
        CGFloat height = size.height + 8;
    }
    else // Row is not expanded
        return 30;
}
```

The same text is fed to both, it consists of a string with multiple new lines `\n`.  If the line is longer than width, word wrap does its job but when calculating its dynamic height, it fails to include the wrapped line.

If I add any value to the `[labelExpanded setFrame:height]` such as `[size.height + 30]` my wrapped line shows up.  However, if the line isn't wrapped, it adds unnecessary whitespace.

I haven't been able to find a solution online for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One thing I note is that you are calculating the size based on a width of 300, but sizing the label at 248.

Answer (score 3):

```
    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(300, 20000);
    CGSize size = [expandedDetails sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    [labelExpanded setText:expandedDetails];
    [labelExpanded setFrame:CGRectMake(16, 30, 248, size.height)];
```

Why is the label frame width 248 and constraint width is 300?