# how can I make iphone views layout auto resized and arranged

Tags: iphone, layout, uitableview, xcode4.2

In my iphone app I have two UITextView inside a cell with frames 
(65,22,210,25) 
(65,40,210,25)
I fill this textviews with strings which i don't know its length (retrive it from database)
My question in tow parts:

1- if the first textview exceed the specific height in its frame it will go over the second textview

2- when those textviews getting bigger in height How can I specify the height of the cell hold them? can i make the cell auto size ??

my current solution for the first question is rearrange the views frame in the layoutSubviews
and for the second question i try to calc the new heights of textviews and pass it to the delegate

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

any better solutions ?

Comment: Default behavior of UITextView is it will automatically add scrolling if text is bigger than its current height.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct. You can use `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` for determining the text size and then calculate cell height at `tableview:heightForRowAtIndexPath`(just remember to include the frame's Y values)

Some more code can be seen here: [UILabel with -[sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode] is cutting off words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439507/uilabel-with-sizewithfontconstrainedtosizelinebreakmode-is-cutting-off-word)

Answer (score 0):

you need to go like this
in your

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

pass a heigh that can hold a `textView` of appropriate height.
Then in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

adjust the height of `textView` accordingly and in both the above methods use `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` to determine the height required